# Check if character is number?

Tags: javascript

I need to check whether `justPrices[i].substr(commapos+2,1)`.

The string is something like: "blabla,120"

In this case it would check whether '0' is a number. How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Comment: @cctan It's not a duplicate. That question is about checking a string, this is about checking a character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Answer (score 128):

You could use comparison operators to see if it is in the range of digit characters:

```
var c = justPrices[i].substr(commapos+2,1);
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    // it is a number
} else {
    // it isn't
}
```

Answer (score 84):

you can either use `parseInt` and than check with `isNaN`

or if you want to work directly on your string you can use regexp like this:

```
function is_numeric(str){
    return /^\d+$/.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Or even simpler if we only need to check a single character: `function is_numeric_char(c) { return /\d/.test(c); }`

Comment: @jackocnr your test will also return true for strings that contains more than just a char (e.g. `is_numeric_char("foo1bar") == true`). if you want to check for a numeric char `/^\d$/.test(c)` would be a better solution. but anyway, it wasn't the question :)

Comment: You can also use typeof like: `typeof parseInt(char, 10) === 'number'`

Answer (score 42):

Simple function:

```
function isCharNumber(c) {
  return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}
```

If you want to ensure `c` is really a single character:

```
function isCharNumber(c) {
  return typeof c === 'string' && c.length === 1 && c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}
```

Comment: This works in languages like C if `c` has type char, but in JS the function will return true for any string that starts with a digit. However if you add something like `c.length == 1 &&` just after the return keyword, I think it's a good solution.

Comment: @optical answer updated accordingly

Comment: I think your second version is still missing a verification, because it would return true for the input `0a-!` for example. I submitted an edit that checks if it's a single character.

Answer (score 41):

EDIT: Blender's updated answer is the right answer here if you're just checking a single character (namely `!isNaN(parseInt(c, 10))`). My answer below is a good solution if you want to test whole strings.

Here is jQuery's `isNumeric` implementation (in pure JavaScript), which works against **full strings**:

```
function isNumeric(s) {
    return !isNaN(s - parseFloat(s));
}
```

The comment for this function reads:

> // parseFloat NaNs numeric-cast false positives (null|true|false|"")
>   // ...but misinterprets leading-number strings, particularly hex literals ("0x...")
>   // subtraction forces infinities to NaN

I think we can trust that these chaps have spent quite a bit of time on this!

Commented source [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deprecated.js#L84). Super geek discussion [here](https://github.com/jquery/contribute.jquery.org/issues/54).

Comment: This works, but it is an overkill for digit-only check (it works with multi-digit numbers). My solution may not be as clear, but is much faster than this.

Answer (score 32):

I wonder why nobody has posted a solution like:

```
var charCodeZero = "0".charCodeAt(0);
var charCodeNine = "9".charCodeAt(0);

function isDigitCode(n) {
   return(n >= charCodeZero && n <= charCodeNine);
}
```

with an invocation like:

```
if (isDigitCode(justPrices[i].charCodeAt(commapos+2))) {
    ... // digit
} else {
    ... // not a digit
}
```

Comment: searched exactly for that kind of solution - ty

Comment: You can drop the 0 parameter value for charCodeAt since 0 is implied when the parameter is not provided.

Answer (score 19):

You can use this:

```
function isDigit(n) {
    return Boolean([true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true][n]);
}
```

Here, I compared it to the accepted method: http://jsperf.com/isdigittest/5 . I didn't expect much, so I was pretty suprised, when I found out that accepted method was much slower.

Interesting thing is, that while accepted method is faster correct input (eg. '5') and slower for incorrect (eg. 'a'), my method is exact opposite (fast for incorrect and slower for correct).

Still, in worst case, my method is 2 times faster than accepted solution for correct input and over 5 times faster for incorrect input.

Comment: I love this answer! Maybe optimize it to: `!!([!0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0][n]);` It has great WTF potential and works quite well (fails for `007`).

Comment: @Jonathan - see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32572539/104380), method #4

Comment: According to this 'solution', `"length"` (and other attributes found on arrays) are digits :P

Answer (score 13):

I think it's very fun to come up with ways to solve this. Below are some.
(All functions below *assume* argument is a single character. Change to `n[0]` to enforce it)

### Method 1:

```
function isCharDigit(n){
  return !!n.trim() && n > -1;
}
```

### Method 2:

```
function isCharDigit(n){
  return !!n.trim() && n*0==0;
}
```

### Method 3:

```
function isCharDigit(n){
  return !!n.trim() && !!Number(n+.1); // "+.1' to make it work with "." and "0" Chars
}
```

### Method 4:

```
var isCharDigit = (function(){
  var a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
  return function(n){
    return !!a[n] // check if `a` Array has anything in index 'n'. Cast result to boolean
  }
})();
```

### Method 5:

```
function isCharDigit(n){
  return !!n.trim() && !isNaN(+n);
}
```

#### Test string:

```
var str = ' 90ABcd#?:.+', char;
for( char of str ) 
  console.log( char, isCharDigit(char) );
```

Comment: Methods 1, 2, 3 and 5 output `true` for `" "`.

Comment: For fun I did a jsperf of these, then added a `charCodeAt()` comparison - which was almost 4x faster - https://jsperf.com/isdigit3

Comment: @Rycochet - good one. ASCII codes range really is the best way to test..

Answer (score 6):

I suggest a simple regex.

If you're looking for just the last character in the string:

```
/^.*?[0-9]$/.test("blabla,120");  // true
/^.*?[0-9]$/.test("blabla,120a"); // false
/^.*?[0-9]$/.test("120");         // true
/^.*?[0-9]$/.test(120);           // true
/^.*?[0-9]$/.test(undefined);     // false
/^.*?[0-9]$/.test(-1);            // true
/^.*?[0-9]$/.test("-1");          // true
/^.*?[0-9]$/.test(false);         // false
/^.*?[0-9]$/.test(true);          // false
```

And the regex is even simpler if you are just checking a single char as an input:

```
var char = "0";
/^[0-9]$/.test(char);             // true
```

Answer (score 6):

The shortest solution is:

```
const isCharDigit = n => n < 10;
```

You can apply these as well:

```
const isCharDigit = n => Boolean(++n);

const isCharDigit = n => '/' < n && n < ':';

const isCharDigit = n => !!++n;
```

if you want to check more than 1 chatacter, you might use next variants

Regular Expression:

```
const isDigit = n => /\d+/.test(n);
```

Comparison:

```
const isDigit = n => +n == n;
```

Check if it is not NaN

```
const isDigit = n => !isNaN(n);
```

Comment: First one seems to be wrong, `n<10` will return true for the space character, for example.

Comment: Boolean(++n) also returns true for the space character.

Answer (score 5):

If you are testing single characters, then:

```js
var isDigit = (function() {
  var re = /^\d$/;
  return function(c) {
    return re.test(c);
  }
}());

['e','0'].forEach(c => console.log(
  `isDigit("${c}") : ${isDigit(c)}`)
);
```

will return true or false depending on whether c is a digit or not.

Comment: Why make isDigit a self-executing function's return function, why not just make it equal to a regular function?

Comment: @Artur—to keep the regular expression in a closure so it doesn't have to be created every time the function is run. Premature optimisation? Perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple function that does it.

```
function is_number(char) {
    return !isNaN(parseInt(char));
}

Returns: true, false
```

Answer (score 4):

Use combination of `isNaN` and `parseInt` functions:

```js
var character = ... ; // your character
var isDigit = ! isNaN( parseInt(character) );
```

Another notable way - multiplication by one (like `character * 1` instead of `parseInt(character)`) - makes a number not only from any numeric string, but also a `0` from empty string and a string containing only spaces so it is not suitable here.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to one of the answers above, I used

```
 var sum = 0; //some value
 let num = parseInt(val); //or just Number.parseInt
 if(!isNaN(num)) {
     sum += num;
 }
```

This blogpost sheds some more light on this [check if a string is numeric in Javascript | Typescript & ES6](https://mydaytodo.com/check-string-is-numeric-javascript-typescript/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var Is = {
    character: {
        number: (function() {
            // Only computed once
            var zero = "0".charCodeAt(0), nine = "9".charCodeAt(0);

            return function(c) {
                return (c = c.charCodeAt(0)) >= zero && c <= nine;
            }
        })()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
isNumber = function(obj, strict) {
    var strict = strict === true ? true : false;
    if (strict) {
        return !isNaN(obj) && obj instanceof Number ? true : false;
    } else {
        return !isNaN(obj - parseFloat(obj));
    }
}
```

output without strict mode:

```
var num = 14;
var textnum = '14';
var text = 'yo';
var nan = NaN;

isNumber(num);
isNumber(textnum);
isNumber(text);
isNumber(nan);

true
true
false
false
```

output with strict mode:

```
var num = 14;
var textnum = '14';
var text = 'yo';
var nan = NaN;

isNumber(num, true);
isNumber(textnum, true);
isNumber(text, true);
isNumber(nan);

true
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function is_numeric(str){
        try {
           return isFinite(str)
        }
        catch(err) {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution by leveraging language's dynamic type checking:

```js
function isNumber (string) {
   //it has whitespace
   if(string.trim() === ''){
     return false
   }
   return string - 0 === string * 1
}
```

see test cases below

```js
function isNumber (str) {
   if(str.trim() === ''){
     return false
   }
   return str - 0 === str * 1
}


console.log('-1' + ' → ' + isNumber ('-1'))    
console.log('-1.5' + ' → ' + isNumber ('-1.5')) 
console.log('0' + ' → ' + isNumber ('0'))    
console.log(', ,' + ' → ' + isNumber (', ,'))  
console.log('0.42' + ' → ' + isNumber ('0.42'))   
console.log('.42' + ' → ' + isNumber ('.42'))    
console.log('#abcdef' + ' → ' + isNumber ('#abcdef'))
console.log('1.2.3' + ' → ' + isNumber ('1.2.3')) 
console.log('' + ' → ' + isNumber (''))    
console.log('blah' + ' → ' + isNumber ('blah'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this:

```
const isNumber = (str) => (
    str && str.length === str.trim().length 
    && str.length > 0
    && Number(str) >= 0
    || Number(str) < 0
)
```

It works for strings or single characters.

Answer (score 1):

modifying this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38370808/10577976) to be little more convenient and limiting to chars(and not string):

```js
const charCodeZero = "0".charCodeAt(0);
const charCodeNine = "9".charCodeAt(0);
function isDigit(s:string) {
    return s.length==1&& s.charCodeAt(0) >= charCodeZero && s.charCodeAt(0) <= charCodeNine;
}

console.log(isDigit('4'))   //true
console.log(isDigit('4s'))  //false
console.log(isDigit('s'))   //false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_numeric(mixed_var) {
    return (typeof(mixed_var) === 'number' || typeof(mixed_var) === 'string') &&
        mixed_var !== '' && !isNaN(mixed_var);
}
```

[Source code](http://phpjs.org/functions/is_numeric/)

Answer (score 0):

```
square = function(a) {
    if ((a * 0) == 0) {
        return a*a;
    } else {
        return "Enter a valid number.";
    }
}
```

[Source](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/983)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (worked in my case)

If you want to test if the first char of a string is an int:

```
if (parseInt(YOUR_STRING.slice(0, 1))) {
    alert("first char is int")
} else {
    alert("first char is not int")
}
```

If you want to test if the char is a int:

```
if (parseInt(YOUR_CHAR)) {
    alert("first char is int")
} else {
    alert("first char is not int")
}
```

Comment: `if (parseInt(YOUR_CHAR))` would not be truish when the character is 0 though :) at least you have to do `if (parseInt(YOUR_CHAR) + 1) ` or better compare to `NaN` => `if (parseInt(YOUR_CHAR) !== NaN)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

**Static binding:**

```
String.isNumeric = function (value) {
    return !isNaN(String(value) * 1);
};
```

**Prototype binding:**

```
String.prototype.isNumeric = function () {
    return !isNaN(this.valueOf() * 1);
};
```

It will check single characters, as well as whole strings to see if they are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

This function works for all test cases that i could find.
It's also faster than:

```
function isNumeric (n) {
  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n) && !hasLeading0s(n)) {
    return true;
  }
  var _n = +n;
  return _n === Infinity || _n === -Infinity;
}
```

```js
var isIntegerTest = /^\d+$/;
var isDigitArray = [!0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0, !0];

function hasLeading0s(s) {
  return !(typeof s !== 'string' ||
    s.length < 2 ||
    s[0] !== '0' ||
    !isDigitArray[s[1]] ||
    isIntegerTest.test(s));
}
var isWhiteSpaceTest = /\s/;

function fIsNaN(n) {
  return !(n <= 0) && !(n > 0);
}

function isNumber(s) {
  var t = typeof s;
  if (t === 'number') {
    return (s <= 0) || (s > 0);
  } else if (t === 'string') {
    var n = +s;
    return !(fIsNaN(n) || hasLeading0s(s) || !(n !== 0 || !(s === '' || isWhiteSpaceTest.test(s))));
  } else if (t === 'object') {
    return !(!(s instanceof Number) || fIsNaN(+s));
  }
  return false;
}

function testRunner(IsNumeric) {
  var total = 0;
  var passed = 0;
  var failedTests = [];

  function test(value, result) {
    total++;
    if (IsNumeric(value) === result) {
      passed++;
    } else {
      failedTests.push({
        value: value,
        expected: result
      });
    }
  }
  // true
  test(0, true);
  test(1, true);
  test(-1, true);
  test(Infinity, true);
  test('Infinity', true);
  test(-Infinity, true);
  test('-Infinity', true);
  test(1.1, true);
  test(-0.12e-34, true);
  test(8e5, true);
  test('1', true);
  test('0', true);
  test('-1', true);
  test('1.1', true);
  test('11.112', true);
  test('.1', true);
  test('.12e34', true);
  test('-.12e34', true);
  test('.12e-34', true);
  test('-.12e-34', true);
  test('8e5', true);
  test('0x89f', true);
  test('00', true);
  test('01', true);
  test('10', true);
  test('0e1', true);
  test('0e01', true);
  test('.0', true);
  test('0.', true);
  test('.0e1', true);
  test('0.e1', true);
  test('0.e00', true);
  test('0xf', true);
  test('0Xf', true);
  test(Date.now(), true);
  test(new Number(0), true);
  test(new Number(1e3), true);
  test(new Number(0.1234), true);
  test(new Number(Infinity), true);
  test(new Number(-Infinity), true);
  // false
  test('', false);
  test(' ', false);
  test(false, false);
  test('false', false);
  test(true, false);
  test('true', false);
  test('99,999', false);
  test('#abcdef', false);
  test('1.2.3', false);
  test('blah', false);
  test('\t\t', false);
  test('\n\r', false);
  test('\r', false);
  test(NaN, false);
  test('NaN', false);
  test(null, false);
  test('null', false);
  test(new Date(), false);
  test({}, false);
  test([], false);
  test(new Int8Array(), false);
  test(new Uint8Array(), false);
  test(new Uint8ClampedArray(), false);
  test(new Int16Array(), false);
  test(new Uint16Array(), false);
  test(new Int32Array(), false);
  test(new Uint32Array(), false);
  test(new BigInt64Array(), false);
  test(new BigUint64Array(), false);
  test(new Float32Array(), false);
  test(new Float64Array(), false);
  test('.e0', false);
  test('.', false);
  test('00e1', false);
  test('01e1', false);
  test('00.0', false);
  test('01.05', false);
  test('00x0', false);
  test(new Number(NaN), false);
  test(new Number('abc'), false);
  console.log('Passed ' + passed + ' of ' + total + ' tests.');
  if (failedTests.length > 0) console.log({
    failedTests: failedTests
  });
}
testRunner(isNumber)
```

Comment: I fixed the '0' case.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple regex solution to check only one char:

```
function isDigit(chr) {
      return  chr.match(/[0-9]/i);
}
```

Comment: this will not return a boolean value; wrap the returned value with Boolen. Also, it will return a match for a chr like "1asd", so you need to modify your regex to only one character, so the final returned value should be: Boolean(this.match(/^[0-9]$/i))

Comment: @Elyasaf755 I did not make any explanation about whether the function returns a boolean value.  You can use the function like that if(isDigit('5')) { ... }

Comment: Naming a function "isSomething" while it's not returning a boolean value is VERY confusing. Also, even the way you explained in the comments how this function should be used is incorrect as I already explained that the function will have a truthy value for the parameter "1asd", meaning that the following code will print "I AM A DIGIT" to console, which is extremely incorrect, try it: if (isDigit("asd123QWERT")) console.log("I AM A DIGIT")

Comment: Why do you pass a string instead of a char as a parameter? The main purpose of the function is to return whether the character given as a parameter is a digit or not.  On the other hand, Developer who will use the code snippet  can add extra control to the function to avoid a sad path.

Answer (score 0):

let ch = '6'; // or any other string that has integer value

Simple function that can be used : !isNaN(ch - '0')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72517845/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the input is string (makes more sense in TypeScript).

```js
const isDigit = (char) => ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'].indexOf(char) !== -1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `isFinite`

```
const number = "1";
if (isFinite(number)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This returns true for a space " "

Answer (score -1):

Try using `isNAN`

generally:

```
isNAN(char)
```

examples:

```
let isNum = !isNAN('5')  // true
let isNum = !isNAN('a')  // false
```

Comment: You have a typo, the proper function name is `isNaN`
Also the returned response is the opposite way you say. It is false when is a number and is true when is not a number.
Another issue is that isNaN is not the most reliable way because boolean values also return `false` and the `null` value also return `false`