# JavaScript separate currency into number value and currency symbol/name

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am getting a currency value from a web service, that I would like to display in a number input (the float part) and it's currency symbol/name on a simple label that's next to the input.

Example of data that I get from the web service:

> $ 1.200,05
>
> R$ 1200.05
>
> kr. 1,200.05
>
> 37,200.05 kr.
>
> $300
>
> 500.0 €

You can see that the data is very mixed.

The symbol/currency name can be before or after the number value, it can have a space between the symbol and the number, or no space at all. It can also have a **dot** inside the currency name, that I would still like to keep (like with the danish krone: **kr.**)

The decimal mark can either be a '**.**'  or a '**,**' and it can be followed by any number of decimals.
Same with the **thousand separator**: it can be either a '.' or a ','

I have the following snippet to get the number value, but i'm having trouble getting the currency string part:

```
if (!isNaN(cost.charAt(0))) { //check whether it starts with number or string, to adjust the regex
    var regex = /([+-]?[0-9|^.|^,]+)[\.|,]([0-9])/
    var result = regex.exec(cost);
    var floatResult = result? result[1].replace(/[.,]/g, "")+ "." + result[2] : cost.replace(/[^0-9-+]/g, "");
    return floatResult;
}
else {
    var regex = /([+-]?[0-9|^.|^,]+)[\.|,]([0-9]+)$/igm
    var result = regex.exec(cost);
    var floatResult = result? result[1].replace(/[.,]/g, "")+ "." + result[2] : cost.replace(/[^0-9-+]/g, "");
    return floatResult;
}
```

I am using jQuery and AngularJS in my webapp, so if there's an easier method with the help of one of those, it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use regex to do this, but what I might do without regex is:

a) record the index of the *first* [numeric character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935632/check-if-character-is-number)

b) record the index of the *last* numeric character

c) take the substring from the first to last numeric characters and convert that to a Number, `Number(numerics)` (you will have to remove commas between numbers for this step)

d) if the first numeric character index is 0, the currency symbol/name will be at the end of the string, *after* the last numeric character

e) otherwise it will be at the front of the string, *before* the first numeric character.

---

## edit

you may be able to simplify the whole thing if you can be certain that what you get back as a response **always** contains one space that seperates the value and the currency symbol. If that were true (as it is in your examples), you could just use `string.split(' ')` to get an array of the two strings, and check which one is the number.