# write a simple decode function in javascript

Tags: javascript, decoding

I am a beginner in javascript and I try to write a simple decoding function.
Here it is:

```
function decode(text) {
let letter, count, i, result, letters;
result = "";
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        count = text[i];
        if (typeof Number(count) === "number") {               
            count = Number(count);
            console.log(count);  // this line only for testing
            letter = text[i + 1];
            letters = letter.repeat(count);
            result += letters;
            console.log(result);  // this line only for testing
        } else {
            result += text[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(decode("v2rt3b2x"));
```

I need help in understanding why the if clause is not being skipped when typeof Number(count) === "number" is false.
It returns this:

```
NaN
VM708:12 
VM708:8 2
VM708:12 rr
VM708:8 NaN
VM708:12 rr
VM708:8 NaN
VM708:12 rr
VM708:8 3
VM708:12 rrbbb
VM708:8 NaN
VM708:12 rrbbb
VM708:8 2
VM708:12 rrbbbxx
VM708:8 NaN
```

As I said, I am a beginner, so please be mercifull...

I got the right answer, but I will try to figure out later why count - 1 works, for now I thank everybody for their help.

```
function decode(text) {
let letter, count, i, result, letters;
result = "";
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    count = parseInt(text[i]);
    if (!isNaN(count)) {               
        //console.log(count);  // this line only for testing
        letter = text[i + 1];
        letters = letter.repeat(count-1);
        //console.log(letters);
        result += letters;
        //console.log(result);  // this line only for testing
    } else {
        result += text[i];
    }
}
return result;
}
console.log(decode("v2rt3b2xz3f2d 2s2 j"));
vrrtbbbxxzfffdd ss  j
```

Comment: typeof Number(n) always return number. Try using if (typeof count === "number") insted of if (typeof Number(count) === "number").

Comment: Thank you very much, but typeof count === "string"

Comment: If you want to check whether a character (from your string) is a digit, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935632/check-if-character-is-number) out.

Answer (score 3):

`typeof Number(x)` will always be `'number'` no matter what `x` is. You are literally casting whatever `x` is to a `'number'` type.

So the if clause is always `true` and never gets skipped.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is located here.

`typeof Number(count) === "number"`

When you try to cast something to number, if it is not possible you will get  `NaN` as the value. And `typeof NaN` is `number`.

Read more about [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Adding `Number.isNaN` check to your if statement will be the solution.

```
function decode(text) {
let letter, count, i, result, letters;
result = "";
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        count = text[i];
        var parsedNumber = Number(count);
        if (!Number.isNaN(parsedNumber)) {               
            letter = text[i + 1];
            letters = letter.repeat(parsedNumber);
            result += letters;
            console.log(result);  // this line only for testing
        } else {
            result += text[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(decode("v2rt3b2x"));
```

Comment: This is not how [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) works. It will always return false here. It returns only true when the actual value is `NaN` (the special value of type Number). You want [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) (the "default" one) instead, ideally after using `parseInt` on it, otherwise it will also consider the space character a number.

Comment: Thank you, I am working on this and I see that I get closer to getting the right result

Comment: @Jeto Well I don't think so. If you look at the implementation of `isNaN`, It just returns if the value can be converted to a number. But` Number.isNaN` returns whether the given value is `NaN`. So, I don't think that we will need `isNaN` for the value we already tried to convert number using `Number(count)`

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven You have edited your code, using `Number.isNaN` on `parsedNumber` is better, but it will still fail for spaces as `Number(' ')` will return `0`, which is a digit. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935632/check-if-character-is-number) pretty much answers this question.

Comment: @Jeto Ok I see now, I forgot to use `parsedNumber` and used `count`. You were right in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the wrong comparison, you could use an approapriate splitting of the string and map the repeated characters.

By taking

> ```
> 'v2rt3b23x'
> ```

and splitting

> ```
> [
>     "v2",
>     "r",
>     "t3",
>     "b23",
>     "x"
> ]
> ```

and mapping

> ```
> [
>     "vv",
>     "r",
>     "ttt",
>     "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
>     "x"
> ]
> ```

you get with `join`

> ```
> 'vvrtttbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbx'
> ```

```js
console.log(
    'v2rt3b23x'
        .split(/(?=\D)/)
        .map(v => v[0].repeat(v.slice(1) || 1))
        .join('')
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much